# Get new value from one input to another

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have two inputs in HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="test1">
<input type="number" id="test2">
```

Now I've an algorithm which should be called after enter of some number in input. For example, if I enter 10 in first input, in twice input must be returned 5 (10/2) without click of any button. So how to archive that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the input event listener.

```
document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("input", function() {
  document.getElementById("test2").value = this.value/2;
})
```

Comment: No problem. Just [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for the next question.